# do we have some mechanism to develop the every chunks together reducing the compile and deployment time?

Tags: java, deployment

There is one scenario where the project has been divided in different chunks .

And the single startup chunks take much time to compile and test.it will be very painful to combine two chunks and develop second one.so what strategy should we opt  separate development of that ?.

or do we have some mechanism to develop the every chunks together reducing the compile and deployment time ?.

Comment: well those are what you would call classes and yes you can compile and test separately as each class/module is supposed to complete a specific task.

Comment: If you have a concise and clear interface between your two chuncks of code, integration shouldn't be a problem. Also consider 'Mock Testing' to test once piece without the other.

Comment: Lest say we have 3 chunks of project's development.

One has been completed but its compilation and deployment time is two high. it would be very difficult to  develop the second chunk by consolidating that files with chunk 1.

Comment: this will just turn into a software dev principles discussion. You are supposed to have little coupling between modules (They are not supposed to depend on each other too much).  1 reason is so they can be developed and tested separately

Comment: Can we make the second chunk working alone?.without deploying the fist one chunk.